# Is there a way to change the naming format for "quick simple product creation"

Tags: admin, configurable-product, simple-product

I've never been a fan of the naming format that the "quick simple product creation" offers you and wondered if there is a native way to tweak it without delving into the code?
For example if the configurable product name is

QWERT
and I create a simple product with the configurable options of Blue and XL it creates the name as

QWERT-Blue-XL

A preferred naming format would be Qwert (Blue/XL)

I know you can uncheck the name option and adjust to what you need but I'm looking for it to automatically stick to the format that I require.

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Magento it makes in controller Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController

```
public function quickCreateAction() {

...

if ($product->getSkuAutogenerate()) {
    $product->setSku($configurableProduct->getSku() . '-' . implode('-', $autogenerateOptions));
}
```

You can rewrite controller or you can do it with event/observer

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <save_model_before>
            <observers>
                <before_save_sku>
                    <model>module/observer</model>
                    <method>updateSku</method>
                </before_save_sku>
            </observers>
        </save_model_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Observer method code:

```
if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'quickCreate') {
    //generate sku as you like and make ->setData('sku', $yourSku)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do this, is creating an observer for `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_quickCreate` and fill in the name automatically based on your logic, if the "autogenerate" checkbox is checked.

This goes into your **config.xml**:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_quickCreate>
            <observers>
                <quick_create_name>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>quick_create_name/observer</class>
                    <method>setQuickcreateName</method>
                </quick_create_name>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_quickCreate>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

And this is an example for your **Observer.php**

```
class SE_QuickCreate_Model_Observer
{
    public function setQuickcreateName(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $request = $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest();
        $simpleProductRequest = $request->getParam('simple_product');
        if (!empty($simpleProductRequest['name_autogenerate'])) {


            $simpleProductRequest['name_autogenerate'] = false;
            $simpleProductRequest['name'] = 'YOUR LOGIC HERE';


        }
        $request->setParam('simple_product', $simpleProductRequest);
    }
}
```